# Как реализуется звуковая передача текста?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом реализуется возможность прослушать текст (новость), как это, например, реализовано [на майл.ру](https://news.mail.ru/economics/39974679/?frommail=1). Что это вообще такое и в какую сторону копать? Очень любопытно, насколько все это сложно. Возможно ли это реализовать только на javascript? Просьба вкратце (на пальцах) описать подобную реализацию. Поиск в интернете мне не дал такой информации (возможно я неправильно задавал поисковые запросы?). Благодарю!
P.S. Спасибо за переоткрытие вопроса! Очень рад, что было принято справедливое решение.

Comment: копать в сторону синтеза речи https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8

Comment: https://music.yandex.ru/album/9294155/track/61062297 - Запись "Турникет в метро тоже искусственный интеллект? Как устроено машинное обучение" - кусочек есть с 15:45 по 17:50.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Добрый вечер. Минут 20 ищу "прослушать новость" по ссылке мейла. Никак не могу найти =((( Натолкните, пожалуйста на пример реализации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Накидал тут небольшую реализацию. )))

В модуле `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` при использовании НЕ стандартного языка произношения - происходят обрывы.
А именно - при прочтении текста, если текст **свыше** 200-300 символов(в зависимости от браузера), то происходит остановка и блокировка воспроизведения. 
Вплоть до того, что ни на одном сайте она более работать не будет пока Вы не перезагрузите браузер. 
Только после этого всё будет работать корректно.

Однако, мне очень не понравилась такая глупая вещь от производителей браузеров. 
Добавил отслеживание эвентов по началу чтения и прекращению.

**Соответственно сделал возможность продолжения чтения. (почти не заметно)**

Вот полный пример реализации:

```js
    var lang = "ru-RU"; // Задаём стандартный язык произношения
    let land = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices(); // Стартовый check, чтобы сразу при нажатии кнопки воспроизводилось.
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.but'); // Ищем кнопки
    buttons.forEach(function (c) { // Для каждой кнопки
        c.addEventListener('click', function () { // Проверяем нажатие
            let parent = c.parentNode.childNodes; // Получаем родителя кнопки, а потом всех детей.
            let text1 = parent[1].innerText; // Заголовок
            let text2 = parent[3].innerText; // Текст новости
            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  // Ставим промис, чтобы успела дочитать до конца сообщение.
                speak(text1); // Читаем первый текст
                resolve();
            });
            promise.then(function() {speak(text2)}); // Читаем второй текст
        });
    });

    function speak(val){ // Функция речи
        var speech = window.speechSynthesis, // Объявляем переменные
            voice = '', // Тссс ))))
            ourvoice = []; // Сюда будем складывать доступные звуки браузера
        if (0 === ourvoice.length) { // Если равно нулю, то...
            var voices = speech.getVoices(); // Получаем все языки
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) { // Находим указанный в списке
            if (lang == voices[i].lang) {
                voice = voices[i]; // Ставим язык как параметр
            }
        }

        var readme = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(val); // вводим текст
        readme.voice = voice; // Задаём язык произношения
        speech.speak(readme); // Произносим

        let startAgain; // Заводим переменнную
        function continueSpeakStupid() { // Стартуем функцию продолжай говорить Глупая!!!
            window.speechSynthesis.resume(); // Продолжаем говорить.
            startAgain = setTimeout(continueSpeakStupid, 1000); // Вызываем заново функцию, чтобы не замолкала никогда. setTimeout чтобы именно функция запускала сама себя в НУЖНЫЙ момент.
        }

        readme.onstart = function(event) { // Отслеживаем евент начала чтения.
            continueSpeakStupid(); // Стартуем функцию, которая продолжает говорить. Функция уже сама запускает сама себя
        };

        readme.onend = function(event) { // Если дочитала
            clearTimeout(startAgain); // Очизаем таймаут. Чтобы функция не крутилась.
        };
    }
```

```css
    .news{
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #d2d2d2;
        text-align: right;
        border: 4px double black;
    }
    .text{
        text-align: center;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #3982ff;
        border: 1px double black;
    }
    .text1{
        text-align: left;
    }
    .news a{
        color: #003eff;
    }
    .news a:hover{
        color: #ff0f2e;
    }
```

```html
<div class="news">
    <div class="text">В Москве задержали мужчину, гулявшего с собакой на Патриарших прудах</div>
    <div class="text1">Мужчину, гулявшего с собакой на Патриарших прудах в Москве и нарушающего режим самоизоляции, задержали из-за невыполнения законных требований полиции, сообщил столичный главк МВД. Согласно указу мэра Москвы, в городе запрещено посещать парки и зоны отдыха до 1 мая.</div>
    <a href="https://yandex.ru/news/story/V_Moskve_zaderzhali_muzhchinu_gulyavshego_s_sobakoj_na_Patriarshikh_prudakh--27077e74e0760b4e81a47712909ebf65?lr=213&lang=ru&stid=fTRJUH917U8KtD64IG-k&persistent_id=93146944&rubric=index&from=index">Ссылка на новость</a>
    <button class="but">Озвучить новость</button>
</div>
<div class="news">
    <div class="text">Искусственный интеллект научился читать мысли</div>
    <div class="text1">Для создания искусственного интеллекта, способного читать мысли, ученые попросили нескольких добровольцев зачитать наборы коротких фраз вслух. Для самой нейросети при этом отбирались только те фразы, которые были повторены хотя бы тремя разными участниками.</div>
    <a href="https://yandex.ru/news/story/Iskusstvennyj_intellekt_nauchilsya_chitat_mysli--d37a7cf9fb77fa285f5c331e97d22b09?lr=213&lang=ru&stid=9V4EzsuLlBm36Ec6vhEM&persistent_id=92646761&rubric=science&from=rubric">Ссылка на новость</a>
    <button class="but">Озвучить новость</button>
</div>
<div class="news">
    <div class="text">Представлена видеокарта GeForce GTX 1650 с памятью GDDR6</div>
    <div class="text1">Для охлаждения видеокарты используются два мощных кулера. Видеокарта MSI GeForce GTX 1650 D6 AERO ITX имеет тактовую частоту – 1 590 МГц, что немного меньше от более производительных ускорителей, потому как это уменьшенный форм-фактор. В систему охлаждения входит один-единственный вентилятор.</div>
    <a href="https://yandex.ru/news/story/Predstavlena_videokarta_GeForce_GTX_1650_s_pamyatyu_GDDR6--b1cd870ad7d55cfa7de7ffb9b1e4c4c1?lr=213&lang=ru&stid=GROVKfvKOGTsAPGEBJB5&persistent_id=92420128&rubric=computers&from=rubric">Ссылка на новость</a>
    <button class="but">Озвучить новость</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Очень актуально про мужчину в парке ))

Comment: Promise так не работают. Если удалишь его, все продолжит работать

Comment: уже лучше, но можно вообще без Promise, похоже `speech.speak` сам себе в очередь складывает